# sed query for pattern matching

Tags: sed

My file looks like

`cat new`:

```
ALL          ALLOFTHEM    ALL1
OPS     BE2A    OPS1

 ABE    ABE     ABE1
```

sed query below gives me the result as 1st line 
`sed -n '/\([A-Z]\{1,\}\)\1/p' new`:

```
ALL          ALLOFTHEM    ALL1
```

I guessed that 2nd line would also match as OPS is also a character length more than 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas is a very generic question, almost always answerable by yes (unless your heave in meditation and you can empty your mind). Try to reformulate the question into something like "how can I ...." that could give us a clue about what you are trying to achieve and would prevent correct, but unhelpful answers like "yes".

Answer (score 2):

> I guessed that 2nd line would also match as OPS is also a character length more than 1.

So, you want to match on any line that has more than one consecutive capital letters?  If so, use:

```
$ sed -n '/[A-Z]\{2,\}/p' new
ALL          ALLOFTHEM    ALL1
OPS     BE2A    OPS1
 ABE    ABE     ABE1
```

*Why doesn't your expression do that?*  Your regex is:

```
\([A-Z]\{1,\}\)\1
```

That breaks down into two parts.  The first is `\([A-Z]\{1,\}\)` which matches one *or* more capital letters.  The second part is `\1` which matches the previous set of capital letters.  This means that a pattern of capital letters has to be repeated (with no intervening characters) for there to be a match.  That matches only the first line because the first line has a capital `L` followed by a capital `L`.  It is the only line with such a sequence.